# Android: Global audio reverb effect

Tags: android, audio, effects

I would like to add a reverb-effect on the global audio-out, which means I would like to modify the audio I can hear when I use any media-player.

Sadly I found no working example, only some which applies the effect on an self-created MediaPlayer-instance.

I tried this one, but none worked:

```
// try #1
EnvironmentalReverb eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(1, 0);
eReverb.setDecayHFRatio((short) 1000);
eReverb.setDecayTime(10000);
eReverb.setDensity((short) 1000);
eReverb.setDiffusion((short) 1000);
eReverb.setReverbLevel((short) 1000);
eReverb.setReverbDelay(100);
eReverb.setEnabled(true);

// try #2
PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(2,0);
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
mReverb.setEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does your app have `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission?

Comment: Yes it has. And the "setEnabled"-command returns "0" which means "SUCCESS".

Comment: Well, the documentation has this to say about the reverb effects: "In order for a MediaPlayer or AudioTrack to be fed into this effect, they must be explicitely attached to it and a send level must be specified. ...  As the EnvironmentalReverb is an auxiliary effect it is recommended to instantiate it on audio session 0 and to attach it to the MediaPLayer auxiliary output". Explicitely attached refers to the attachAuxEffect method in the MediaPlayer/AudioTrack classes.

Comment: Hm, yes I read this but I don't know how this could be applied to a MediaPlayer which is not under my own control, e.g. from another application.. :)

Comment: My interpretation is: it can't.

Comment: I am looking for the same, If you have got the solution for this problem then please help me....

Comment: Sorry, no solution yet!

Answer (score 0):

i think because combine some method with another method value sound effect not sensation e.g("**setReflectionsLevel**" with "**setRoomLeve**")

add this two method and test again.

```
eReverb.setReflectionsLevel(-8500);
eReverb.setRoomLevel(-8500);
```